# Cant get my Eclipse compiler warnings in my PDE Build

Tags: eclipse, ant, javac, eclipse-pde

So, we have a Eclipse product build that builds several plugins. For each of these plugins we have a settings file that defines what JDT compiler warnings we want to know about. It works fine in our Eclipse environment, but not when building.

[Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_compiler_options.htm) that tells me to add "javacProjectSettings=true", problem is, its not really working.

I've added it to the build.properties file for the product build. I've added it to the build.properties in each plugin. 
But I'm not noticing any change at all. It feels like I'm missing something?

The JavaC arguments that seem relevant from the product builds build.properties file:

```
logExtension=.log
javacDebugInfo=true
javacFailOnError=true
javacVerbose=true
compilerArg=-enableJavadoc
javacSource=1.5
javacTarget=1.5
javacProjectSettings=true
```

Comment: Which compiler do you use while building - javac or [Eclipse Compiler for Java](http://thecoderlounge.blogspot.com/2010/05/ecj-eclipse-java-compiler.html) ? I do not think javac can understand JDT compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The `javacProjectSettings=true` property needs to go in the build.properties for each bundle.  It does not go in the top level  product build build.properties.

If you don't want to change the individual bundles' build.properties files, then you could try setting something like

```
compilerArg=-properties .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
```

But I don't know if this relative path works or not.

Otherwise you would need to use compilerArg with `-err:` and `-warn:` which are described in the [JDT help](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm)